# How to establish a 3D model with a 3D array with grayscale values? [python]

Tags: python, arrays, 3d

I have a 3D array, each element in this array is the grayscale value. The position of the elements stand for the position of the voxel in the cube. I would like to transform the array into a 3D cube model using python. But I did not find a good way. Could anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the marching cubes algorithm ([here](https://youtu.be/M3iI2l0ltbE) is a good video explaining it), and the [python stl library](https://python-stl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create an usable file.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But the video is in C#, is there any python library I can use?

Comment: [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html) seems do do the job you want.